# sqlps transaction issue

Tags: sql, powershell, ssas, sqlps

I wrote a script that uses sqlps to deploy a SSAS tabular cube. After the deployment, I need to perform a couple of actions on the cube but if I try to access it, I get a message saying that the cube doesn't exist. But it does, in fact, if I split the actions into two scripts (deploy -> exit sql ps -> new sqlps session), it works (for reasons that don't matter now, I cant do that).

It seems that the sqlps session doesn't see the cube it just deployed. I'm wondering if there is a refresh command I can run or if I can run sqlps in a "read uncommited" state.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use the [PowerShell Transactions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2008/05/09/powershell-transactions-quickstart.aspx) supporting cmdlets? Looks like the transaction is being commited only after your script runs out.

Try to split the deploying logic into two transactions: creating the cube and the other actions you need to perform. For each of this parts you should use it's own transaction, like this:

```
Start-PSTransaction
// logic
Complete-PSTransaction
```

If you need to access the transactions programmatically, you should use the `TransactionScope` analog in the PowerShell, the Cmdlet's [`CurrentPsTransaction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.currentpstransaction.aspx) property, like this:

```
using(CurrentPsTransaction)
{
   ... // Perform transactional work here
}

... // Perform non-transacted work here

using(CurrentPsTransaction)
{
   ... // Perform more transactional work here
}
```

**Update:**
May be you can turn on the transaction using the declaration?

> Developing for transactions – Cmdlet and Provider declarations
>   Cmdlets declare their support for transactions in a similar way that they declare their support for ShouldProcess:
>
> ```
> [Cmdlet(“Get”, “Process”, SupportsTransactions=True)]
> ```
>
> Providers declare their support for transactions through the ProviderCapabilities flag:
>
> ```
> [CmdletProvider(“Registry”, ProviderCapabilities.Transactions)]
> ```

More about the isolation levels in Powershell:

[TransactionScope with IsolationLevel set to Serializable is locking all SQL SELECTs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3628620/transactionscope-with-isolationlevel-set-to-serializable-is-locking-all-sql-sele)

Comment: Hi, I dont seem to be able to run Start-PSTransaction, I get a message "The term 'Start-PSTransaction' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program." I tried just "Start-Transaction" which doesn't fail but also doesn't seem to actually start a transaction because the problem persists.
Aby ideas? Thanks

Comment: Updated the answer, but can't say for sure will it help or not.

Comment: @Diego May be you should add some module in your PS script.

Comment: I tried to add [Cmdlet(“Get”, “Process”, SupportsTransactions=True)] to the top of the script but it complains about syntax error

Comment: @Diego Can't say for sure how to rule out this issue. May be you can provide some code to investigate?